# How to set task status in celery chain

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, task, celery

I need to run three tasks which need to be ran in a chain. So when i request comes i need to run three tasks in this order. Each task gets input from the previous one.

```
Request--->
    [First Task] -> [Second Task] -> [Third Task]

Parent of third = second
Parent of second = first
```

I need to set the status of the chained request from each of the sub tasks(using ajax to retrieve the status). The id of the chain is equal to the id of the [Third Task] so being in third task i can set the chain status but how to set the status from other two tasks.

Comment: Wjat have you tried to far?

Comment: What do you mean by status? Success/failure?

Comment: I've tried using current_task.update_status() but that only sets status for the current task..I want to set status of [Third task] from [First task] and [Second task]. Is there a way by which I can get third task instance from second task(as they belong to the same chain)

By status i mean (Sucess/Failure/Complete/Custom Status with meta data)

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
current_app.AsyncResult({task-id}).[status|results]
```

Where task id is the first, second, third, task. You can also use celery.inspect to see which tasks are currently being scheduled or executed.